# How to handle forms that work with more than one model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model `Question` which has many `Answers`, resulting in a type of form that is given below. What would be the best way of handling the forms which work with more than one model?

[image]

Possible solutions I can think of are:

1. Creating a common `QuestionsAnswersController`
   **Problem:** The code in the controller becomes huge, as it works with two separate models. This approach does not "feel right".
2. Creating separate `QuestionsController` and `AnswersController`.
   **Problem:** I don't understand how exactly will the submitted form be handled.

So, what will be the best solution for this problem?

Comment: you can submit it in any one controller and in there , you can insert data into both table

Comment: Why is the code in your QuestionsAnswersController becoming huge? It sounds like the problem may lie in how you're implementing this within the controller. A single controller is definitely the right approach, but you may have some optimisations you could make within the controller itself. Can you share the controller function you're currently using to process the form?

Comment: i have same problem @Alexander

Comment: @ParthChavda I ended up with `QuestionsAnswersController`, though I don't like this approach